# Broken PHP web app (w/ Bluemix) - MySQLi stops script

Tags: php, json, mysqli, ibm-cloud

I'm building a simple PHP webservice/webapp that when queried from an external application will return JSON formatted/encoded data from a MySQL database.

The PHP webapp and MySQL database are on Bluemix (and MUST to stay there).

Here is my current code for a typical PHP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Before Outside of php</p>
    <?php
    /*
     * Following code will list all the customers
     */

    echo "<p>Before Inside of php</p>";

    $server = "Server";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "database";

    echo "<p>1 Inside of php</p>";

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $mysqli = new mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

    echo "<p>2 Inside of php</p>";

    $response = array();

    echo "<p>3 Inside of php</p>";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM customer")) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $response[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    echo "<p>4 Inside of php</p>";

    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();

    echo "<p>After Inside of php</p>";
    ?>
    <p>Before Outside of php</p>


</body>
</html>
```

I have put in the `<p>1 Inside of PHP<p>` stuff in there so I could see where the script stopped and therefore figure out why.

The last thing that gets echo'd to the screen is `<p>1 Inside of php</p>` so therefore we can assume it's the MySQLi functions not working.
After some googling, I found that the main reason for this was that the MySQLi extension hasn't been included in the installation/build of the PHP webapp.

I am using this buildpack:

```
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git
```

which allows for use of a .bp-config/options.json file to include any extensions not included in the build pack.
As MySQLi is not included in the buildpack. My `.bp-config/options.json` file shows as follows:

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["mysqli"]
}
```

Now that MySQLi is included, I threw a `phpinfo();` in my PHP before the MySQLi function, just to double check, and it displayed all the PHP information WITH a section titled: MySQLi.

Just to point out, the MySQLi section wasn't there before I wrote the `.bp-config/options.json` file.

However, the script STILL stops at the first MySQLi function and won't display anything after that. I'm stumped. Is it Bluemix's fault? Is it my PHP? Do I need to do something else before MySQLi is properly installed? I don't know, Help?

Comment: Basic debugging will help you here.Set `error_reporting` and `display_errors`. End throw an error when the database connection fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP is a little wrong on the line with `mysqli_connect`.

It should be `$mysqli = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);`.  Notice the reference to new is not used.

[`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/mysqli_connect) is a function, not a class. What you want is either:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(...);
```

or

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
```

Both are equivalent.

Additionally the use of `MYSQL_ASSOC` should be `MYSQLI_ASSOC`.
Here is a full replacement of your code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Before Outside of php</p>
    <?php
    /*
     * Following code will list all the customers
     */

    echo "<p>Before Inside of php</p>";

    $server = "Server";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "database";

    echo "<p>1 Inside of php</p>";

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

    echo "<p>2 Inside of php</p>";

    $response = array();

    echo "<p>3 Inside of php</p>";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM customer")) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $response[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    echo "<p>4 Inside of php</p>";

    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();

    echo "<p>After Inside of php</p>";
    ?>
    <p>Before Outside of php</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was perfect. I just needed to change one more thing which was changing the MYSQL_ASSOC to MYSQLI_ASSOC.